# python ftp: transferred file content has no spaces

Tags: python, ftp

this below code is working fine, but the issue is that the transferred file has no spaces , everything is in single line

```
ftp =FTP('x.x.x.x')
ftp.login('user','password')
filename = "test.txt"
local = open(filename, 'wb')
ftp.cwd('/root/Desktop')
ftp.retrbinary('RETR '  +filename, local.write,1024)
```

say test.txt had

```
1)one

2)two

3)three
```

the test.txt thats copied from the reemote server  has

```
1)one2)two3)three
```

everything in one line,

any help pls.

Comment: Are you transferring between a Unix and a Windows machine?

Comment: yes btwn linux to windows @RobertMoskal

Answer (score 0):

To quote the internet:

http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~krueger/csc209h/tut/line-endings.html

> Text files created on DOS/Windows machines have different line endings
>   than files created on Unix/Linux. DOS uses carriage return and line
>   feed ("\r\n") as a line ending, which Unix uses just line feed ("\n").

It's the writing binary that's causing your problem.  It prevents the translation which should be automatic when writing as text. Can you transfer and save as a text file?  You can use retrlines instead of retrbinary.

```
ftp =FTP('x.x.x.x')
ftp.login('user','password')
filename = "test.txt"
local = open(filename, 'w')
ftp.cwd('/root/Desktop')
ftp.retrlines('RETR '  +filename, local.write)
```

Comment: could you please tell me how can i solve this issue in the above script?

Comment: retrlines also giving same result :(

Comment: ftp.storlines('STOR '  +filename, local)       this is working fine but from local to remote(upload),  wanted it to work for remote to local(download)

Comment: That's surprising. Are you certain you removed the Binary flag off the open call? You can also force a line ending by passing in a newline parameter.